Strange behaviour of the in-operator on NumPy arrays
This behavior of the in operator on NumPy arrays I don't understand:
>>> a=[0,1,2]
>>> x=np.array([a])
>>> b=[3,4,5]
>>> np.append(x,[b],axis=0)
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
>>> a in x
True
>>> b in x
False

I want to build a list of distinct vectors so I need the in operator and a way to extend my list of vectors so that an appended element is also seen as being in the list. I use a NumPy array because the in operator doesn't work the way I expect.

In the above example, why is b not seen as an element of y?
How can I append a NumPy array to a NumPy array of NumPy arrays so that the in operator works as expected?
Is there a better way to store vectors (i.e. NumPy array of size 3) so I can add new vectors, and such that the in operator sees newly added vectors as elements of the structure?


np.append isn't modifying x or y in place, so the value you see returned by it is not x.

Partial duplicate? testing whether a Numpy array contains a given row

@wjandrea IMHO it is not duplicate. The derogated post has a very different, if not opposite, initial assumption to start from. This post starts from a green-field, only to construct ( using whatever construction "strategy" and "storage"-representation ) a smart search-able entity, into which only new values ( vectors ) are to get stored. The linked post so deals with different initial conditions and thus resorts to different solutions than O/P stated for this post.

@user3666197 Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean and I can't seem to find relevant definitions for these words you used: derogated, green-field. Also, if it's important, note that I said partial duplicate, not complete duplicate.

A "green-field" is commonly used to say, "(...) there was nothing in the beginning (of the construction)", like when architects start to sketch a new building on, indeed, a green field. The word "derogated" may cause some troubles in plain English, not so in legal and/or technical texts - please accept my apology for unintended potential misunderstanding. The phrase "derogated post" was used to mention the ( lexically remote ) post you pointed to, in the claim, the O/P might be "Partial" duplicate, which it is not, as technical arguments presented and proposals to Close O/P hurt.

@wjandrea Thank you for taking care of clarifications, where needed. It improves our human-to-human understanding and I learned my part from this exchange.

np.append does not modify the array in place. It creates a new array containing b as the second row, but x remains the same.
>>> np.append(x,[b],axis=0)
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
>>> x
array([[0, 1, 2]])
>>> b in np.append(x,[b],axis=0)
True

Also, in makes no sense in the first place for NumPy arrays. row in two_d_array doesn't test whether row is a row of two_d_array. It gives you (row == two_d_array).any(), which for a 1D row and a 2D two_d_array, tests whether any element of row shows up as an element of the corresponding column of two_d_array.

There is more to it though, as x = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3,4,5]]) followed by
print([0, 1, 7] in x) returns True. See this post

@chepner: thanks for clearing this up. In view of this, what would be the correct way to check for whether a particular numpy array is a row of  a two-d arrayi?

Could you please confirm your proposed solution O(N)-complexity costs? Not meaning the adverse costs of repetitive re-allocations of new memory for each np.append(), just for your proposed "in"-ness testing? Details in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78625002/strange-behaviour-of-the-in-operator-on-numpy-arrays#comment138620247_78625309

I found a work-around for my problem:

use a simple list to store my vector (numpy arrays)

write a function which checks if a particular vector is contained in the list:
def contains(vlist, vector):
    for v in vlist:
        if (v == vector).all():
            return True
    return False


if not contains(my_list, new_vector):
    my_list.append(new_vector)



That way i get the functionality i need.

You could simplify that function to return any((v == vector).all() for v in vlist)

You should be aware that performance-wise this for-based Python-list "top-down" approach might work, yet is prohibitively inefficient if compared to a hash-able based associative seek ( that does not iterate values, but rather jumps to pre-index-ed key, so enjoys O( 1 ) performance for { in | not in }-matching tests, no matter how many vectors you have, be it millions, billions or anything alike ). Your def'ed contains() is only O( N )-slow and the .append() is even worse, as it devastates performance & memory ( gc.collect()-able ex-post ) in each call, as it allocated a fresh memory+copy I/Os

You can apply the ==/all test without iterating on rows
In [9]: >>> a=[0,1,2]
   ...: >>> x=np.array([a])
   ...: >>> b=[3,4,5]
   ...: >>> x=np.append(x,[b],axis=0)
   ...: x
Out[9]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])

In [10]: x==a
Out[10]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False]])

x is (2,3).  np.array(a) is (3,), so this equality works (by broadcasting) to make a (2,3) boolean array.
Then just test that all columns are True.
In [11]: (x==a).all(1)
Out[11]: array([ True, False])

In [12]: (x==b).all(1)
Out[12]: array([False,  True])

You could leave these a (2,) arrays, or apply an any to reduce them to a scalar boolean.

Do I understand it correctly, that this proposed syntax will, for example for some 1E+9 such [n1,n2,n3]-vectors, first & repeatedly always process all vector-items down the line, inside the .append()-ed storage-array, so as to next, again repeatedly always process all such interim logical booleans, reducing them all next or not, as a repetitive block-cost of such proposed implementation of "in"-ness-test ( going thus about to be no better than O( N ) ) or did I miss some key benefit or performance shortcut somewhere around O( log N )?

The O(...) isn't changed (may even be worse). It's just that more work is done in compiled code, and less at the interpreter level. With the possibility of early exit, your iteration may be faster in some examples.

Thank you for you kind response, sure smart, compiled code the numpy is known for since ever, helps in many cases, yet what "( your ) iteration" do you mean? there is nothing like iteration in an "in"-operator evaluation over associative hash-able key-indexed associative storage, iirc. I lost your point in this.

Your answer has an early exit if found; mine doesn't. Python any also short circuits, numpy any does not.  Searching isn't a strong feature of numpy methods.  Numpy arrays aren't hashable (nor are lists).  You have to convert them to tuples or strings to take advantage of python's hashing tools.

Aha, thank you. Would you agree, the wording "early exit" should rather be, due to the very design principle of the hash-based efficient seek, replaced with "a minimum overhead seek time", which is exactly what the associative key:value storage tools are so well known for having built-in & performance polished in their design? "Early exit" sounds more like "(...) once I started trivial linear O(N) top-down searching, I enjoy not to have to complete the rest of N-cases, once I found a first match, just by coincidence (and next time I will again start top-down battle down the hill )..."?

@wjandrea's link  is a good discussion of 'short-circuiting' issue.  Rereading the original question, I have 2 thoughts.  It is faster to grow a list. What is wrong with using in with the list of lists? Do you really need 3 element arrays?

With all due respect, there is nothing like "short-circuiting" or "early exit" difference. It is a principal difference both in TimeDOMAIN-performance and SpaceDOMAIN-efficiency. Numpy was well tuned for broadcasting-/vectorised-tricks, using optimised, SIMD-INSTRs(where avail.) compiled code. Yet, the O/P asked 3 very different questions. Addressed Q3+comments w an O(1) performing associative search (hidden in the in-operator O/P asked to use) for fast matches, even ultimately fastest, ConstTIME + ZeroSPACE (0 memIOs+0 allocs) response for not in-matches, I face downvote + closing O/P?

@user3666197, sorry when I mentioned 'your answer', I had in mind the one that the OP posted, which iterates the rows, and exits if there's a match.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/78625194/901925.  I wasn't paying close attention to the different 'user...' names :)

@user3666197, 'search/in' tasks are not a strong point for numpy code.  Some python functions do short-circuit (e.g. 'or/and'), but not the numpy equivalents.  Years ago when I was trying to replicate a typical lisp algorithm  in numpy, I resorted to writing a cython function for one searching step.  Now numba is widely recommended for custom compiling.

(This answer does not compete for performance or optimality, it only addresses a way how to use an in-operator over vectors, as was asked above)

is there a better way to store vectors (i.e. numpy array of size 3), to that I can add new vectors, and such that the in operator sees newly added vectors as being elements of the structure?

We may "decimate" arrays into hash-able format:
   aDict = { x.tobytes(): 1, }
   aDict
{'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00': 1}

and enjoy the syntax of in-operator over ( hash-able ) dictionary keys, perhaps with some added benefits from ability to associate some additional data to such "vector"-keys, like for frequencies of occurences or any more complex data structures in key-value contents the dictionaries are designed for :
>>> x.tobytes() in aDict
True
>>> aDict[ np.array([b]).tobytes() ] = 1
>>> aDict
{'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00': 1, '\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00': 1}

Using ( almost )-any-value-resistant method for creating a hash-able key, like dill.dumps( newX ) in aDictOfVECTORs, both solves all the below listed commented objections, and retains the core advantage of using hash-able key:value(s) associative method - the performance - remaining, no matter what size / length aDictOfVECTORs grows into, just O( 1 ) right due to use of hash-able associative storage. No memory thrashing, no ( repetitively ) wasted CPU-cycles.
We receive an unbeatable O( 1 ) performance as a side-effect from using a smart hash-able associativity for testing a Hamletesque { in | not in } question.

This may produce unexpected results for negative zeros, NaNs, or mismatching dtypes (including mismatching byte orders), though.

@user2357112 could you clarify that? "decimated"-hash is what we welcome to use, not to reconstruct the original, as we sure loose many of numpy-original attributes, nevertheless, we can even store the original besides its own "decimated"-hashable, if need be, so where is the problem?

It'll consider -0.0 unequal to 0.0. It'll consider numpy.array([1.0]) equal to numpy.array([4607182418800017408]). It'll consider numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4]) equal to numpy.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]). It might or might not consider NaNs equal to each other, depending on the exact bit pattern used to represent them. It'll consider a big-endian 1 equal to a little-endian 72057594037927936 rather than a little-endian 1 (which can matter, particularly if you serialize arrays on one machine and deserialize on another).

You can avoid these sorts of pitfalls, but it takes careful work and increases the probability of bugs.

@user2357112 thank you for your explanations. The core focus was on moving towards use of standard in-operator, which was the O/P intention, where Python handling of "storage"-container gets fast on dictionaries, instead of diving into numpy-specific workarounds for engineering complex "equality" tests within ( no doubts very powerful for numerical processing ) syntax-tricks available for np.ndarray()-instances. You might have noticed, only the "SER"-(not the DES)-part was proposed for turning smart numpy vector-of-3 ( though unspecified ) items, as hash-able result enables use of in-operator

Which was the O/P intent, wasn't it? Claims about np-arrays content could extend to cases, like arrays-of-objects, for sure, yet as a hash-able is the goal, we need not worry here, we can, if in doubts, proceed to hash-able using dill.dumps()-smart-serialiser, to indeed generate an (almost-)everything-proof method to get a reproducible hash-able, that the dictionary in-operator will work as smooth as the O/P wanted. Q.E.D. Let's enjoy the Fathers' Day
